# How do I calculate "Business Use " of my home when I moved mid-year?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I am trying to figure out how to fill out my schedule C.

My wife has a direct sales business that she started in January 2013. We moved out of state at the end of June. Both dwellings were used partially for the business, so I am filling out Form 8829. Do I just fill out Form 8829 twice (one for each home) and then add the allowable expenses from the two forms and put that on my schedule C line 30?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a separate Form 8829 for each home used for business during the year. The top of [8829](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8829.pdf) includes that exact instruction.